# We're all winners somehow?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Swimming peacefully to reach my goal,
>   Using no arms to reach the col.
>
> Fruit of the effort I am,
>   Even though men go ham.
>
> Many brothers and sisters,
>   Yet only one winner.
>
> I have no ex and you may ask me why,
>   The answer, my friend, is that I'm a little shy.
>
> Don't be fooled, I can still knock,
>   But I might stay on the rock.

How old am I must likely, and who am I ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> the Y chromosome sperm cell

Swimming peacefully to reach my goal,
Using no arms to reach the col.

> Well...it does not have arms

Fruit of the effort I am,
Even though men go ham.

> You got to put "some effort" into it (if you know what I mean)

Many brothers and sisters,
Yet only one winner.

> Only the first one gets the egg.

I have no ex and you may ask me why,
The answer, my friend, is that I'm a little shy.

> The Y chromosome cell does not have an X one with it.

Don't be fooled, I can still knock,
But I might stay on the rock.

> Knock as in "knocked-up".

Comment: Congrats, i'll accept when I can. was too easy I guess :)

Comment: Also, the title has another hint. If one of them reaches the egg, the act was successful, so in a way they are "all winners".

Answer (score 1):

> A spermatozoid

Swimming peacefully to reach my goal,
Using no arms to reach the col.

> The goal is the egg cell. The col, in French, is the cervix, but that's a little strange here.

Fruit of the effort I am,
Even though men go ham.

> Result of making love.

Many brothers and sisters,
Yet only one winner.

> Only one to reach the egg

I have no ex and you may ask me why,
The answer, my friend, is that I'm a little shy.

> Not sure about this. Maybe has not inseminated before (don't know how to say in English)

Don't be fooled, I can still knock,
But I might stay on the rock.

> ?

Comment: good answer too, but marius got all the details and the more precise answer. still +1

Comment: Ha ha ...the col is "the cervix" in French. This is actually funny if you think of it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess...

> spermathozoid (sry typos)
>  they have no arms, and have to swim up the river.
>  they are tons of thems, which all would be brothres/sisters, yet only 1 gets to the goal.

Comment: Wow, synchro with the others, you got it right, but marius got the most details, nice one still

Comment: I was about to say a "salmon", but right as I was typing the explanation for "swimming up the river, and no arms" I thought, wtf...that's not a fish xD